# Need Help in downloading repositories from different nexus sources

Tags: maven-2, nexus

I am a newbie to Nexus and Maven , trying a example where
I have to download three different repositories from three different sources , Source 1. Maven repository i.e. maven's website. 2. A Local Nexus installed and running on my local machine, 3. Another private source of Nexus from which third party jars are downloaded from a private nexus deployed at some other server.

Please help me or give me a direction from where I can do this. I know a little bit about modifications of setting.xml and pom.xml. I am able to download repository from my local nexus  by configuring the settings.xml and pom.xml.

Regards,
Yash.

Comment: http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/config.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the Answer to my question, this can be done by adding different nexus repository in the pom.xml of maven repository in the repositories tag,
e.g.

```
<repository>
        <id>repositryID</id>
        <name>repositoryName</name>
        <url>http://NexusserverRepositoryHOST1:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
<repository>
        <id>repositryID</id>
        <name>repositoryName</name>
        <url>http://NexusserverRepositoryHOST2:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```